# Parse complex XMLattributes with multiple elements under root - JAXB and make object model

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to parse the XML string into Object. Please find the class and XML string details below

**Country class**

```
public class Country {

    private String Country_Name;
    private String Country_Capital;
    private String Country_Foundation_Date;
    private String Country_Continent;
    private String Country_Population;

    public String getCountry_Name() {
        return Country_Name;
    }
    public void setCountry_Name(String country_Name) {
        Country_Name = country_Name;
    }
    public String getCountry_Capital() {
        return Country_Capital;
    }
    public void setCountry_Capital(String country_Capital) {
        Country_Capital = country_Capital;
    }
    public String getCountry_Foundation_Date() {
        return Country_Foundation_Date;
    }
    public void setCountry_Foundation_Date(String country_Foundation_Date) {
        Country_Foundation_Date = country_Foundation_Date;
    }
    public String getCountry_Continent() {
        return Country_Continent;
    }
    public void setCountry_Continent(String country_Continent) {
        Country_Continent = country_Continent;
    }
    public String getCountry_Population() {
        return Country_Population;
    }
    public void setCountry_Population(String country_Population) {
        Country_Population = country_Population;
    }
}
```

**Parse Code Implementation**

```
    import java.io.StringReader;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
    import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

    public class ParseXMLStringtoObject {

        public static String getXMLString() {

            StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
            returnString.append("<output xmlprop = \"somevalue\"> ");
            returnString.append("<Country> ");
            returnString.append("<Country_Name equals=\"Spain\" type=\"1\" /> ");
            returnString.append("<Country_Capital equals = \"Madrid\" type=\"1\" /> ");
            returnString.append("<Country_Foundation_Date equals=\"1469-10-19\" type=\"3\" /> ");
            returnString.append("<Country_Continent equals=\"Europe\" type = \"1\" /> ");
            returnString.append("<Country_Population equals=\"45\" type = \"2\" /> ");
            returnString.append("</Country> ");

            return returnString.toString();
        }

        public static Object getObjectFromStringXml(Class<Country> country)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
            Object obj = getObject(country.newInstance());
            try {
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(getXMLString());
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(country);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                JAXBElement<?> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), country);
                obj = root.getValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.printf("Exception occoured while unmarshalling xml String to " + obj.getClass() +" Object", e);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        private static Object getObject(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Country) {
                obj = (Country) obj;
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Country country = new Country();
            //Class<Country> countryObj = new Class<Country>(); // I don't know how to convert my Country object 
            //or don't know the input value to the getObjectFromStringXml method


            ParseXMLStringtoObject parseXML = new ParseXMLStringtoObject();
            try{
//This is the place I have the doubt to call the parse method, regarding input              
Object obj = parseXML.getObjectFromStringXml(Class<Country> countryObj);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Where type attribute indicates the type of the values present in equals attribute. For example 1 indicates String, 2 indicates int and 3 indicates list.

Can anyone let me know the solution to map the above xml string into Java Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try unmarshalling to java object using JAXB something like below:

```
public static Object getObjectFromStringXml(String xml, Class<Country> country)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
            Object obj = getObject(country.newInstance());
            try {
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(country);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
                JAXBElement<?> root = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(
                        reader), country);
                obj = root.getValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("Exception occoured while unmarshalling xml String to " + obj.getClass() +" Object", e);
            }
            return obj;
        }

        private static Object getObject(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Country) {
                obj = (Country) obj;
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Arpan  (@Arpan - https://stackoverflow.com/users/8561371/arpan)

Thanks for your reply, I tried to include your login into actual program. But I am not clear about Class<Country> country.

Can you please help me on the input to the method you wrote. Please the updated question with actual class implementation.